# Drupal Views: Create 3-Column Home Page with Taxonomy Terms

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-theming

I am looking to create a 3-column home page design for my site that segregates 3 different items of a given taxonomy type (News, Training Alerts, and Advisories) into 3 separate columns. Each column shows not only the taxonomy term, but pulls the content associated with it (e.g. a teaser view of each item marked 'News').

I am not very familiar with Drupal themes, but currently I have been able to accomplish everything I've wanted with my site using the Bartik theme. Are there any ways I can accomplish this using Views and without having to change much about the Bartik theme? Or alternatively, is there a way to just create a table with PHP code that pulls the content associated with each taxonomy type into each column of a 3-column table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of:

1. Create 3 separate block displays, one for each term, using the Content -> Teaser output.
2. Download/enable [Blockgroup](http://dgo.to/blockgroup) and create a new block region (called "Front Categories") and place it wherever and assign it to
3. Put those 3 block displays inside the new block group region in whatever order you would like.
4. Add some simple CSS to give the blocks an even width, like: `.region-blockgroup-front-categories .block-views {width: 33%;}`

That should get you about 90% of the way there, if not completely work out for you.